# Magento 2 : How to add progessive bar(>) after next button in checkout page

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I want to change text name of next button in checkout page

```
<button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
</button>
```

My shippig.phtml file path is : `/var/www/html/choice-brands/pub/static/frontend/Kensium/Choi‌​cebrand/en_US/Magent‌​o_Checkout/template/‌​shipping.html`

I wrote code in shipping.html

```
     <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</button>
```

but nothing change.

I did static content everything but not coming and in inspect element its not shows nothing what i am adding class.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to delete static content and run deploy again. Need to clear Magento Cache and Browser Cache as well.

Comment: is font awesome library included with your theme?

Comment: i did static content everything but not cmg  @Khoa TruongDinh

Comment: in inspect element its not shows nothing what iam adding class @Manish Joy

Comment: path is correct or not : /var/www/html/choice-brands/pub/static/frontend/Kensium/Choicebrand/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html